# Amazon s3: hide a specific bucket to a specific group

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an amazon S3 account with 2 buckets in them. Lets call them "BUCKET A" and "BUCKET B". I also created a group full of users, lets call it "GROUP1".

I do not understand JSON, but have managed to correctly setup a group policy granting access to the GROUP1 members to:

- see (list) all of my buckets in my account (BUCKET A and BUCKET B)
- access BUCKET B (double click and see the folders within)
- access the user's individual folder within BUCKET B, and upload files there.

When they try to double click any folder but their own, access is denied- awesome!

However, to add one more level of security/increase the user friendy experience, I want to hide BUCKET A from sight altogether, so that upon login the users of the group only see 'BUCKET B' and do not even know that BUCKET A exists.

Can someone offer the correct code for this?

Many thanks in advance.

Leo

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible in AWS Console because the API responsible to list all buckets (s3:ListAllMyBuckets) does not support resource level permission hence must be used with [resource "*"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-with-s3-actions.html).

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. To be honest security is my number one concern- can I sleep relatively easy at night in the knowledge that a rogue user could not hack his way into the other folders to which he does not have access? How secure is S3 in this regards?

Comment: Well, if the user doesn't have permission from any source (IAM, S3 bucket policy, ACL etc.), he/she cannot access other objects. Just make sure they don't have IAM permission to elevate their access level or access to change bucket policy and have a regular audit/check of the access level.

Comment: Ok, I will do. Thanks again for the useful advice- really appreciate it.